# what decides how certain programming languages are different from other ones?

Tags: assembly

Im a new dev out there, this question was been spooky in my mind for a long time:
what decides how certain languages are different from other ones?
look, if im correct (i dont know to be honest) there is this certain language in contact with the cpu, which is assembly i thought...
and there are dosens of languages who took over functions and stuff from assembly, but in other 'language'.
why they dont just add EVERY functionality from assembly to EVERY language they create, like that they dont goto learn 20 languages to do some different things..
so for example, i create a language called spooky and i want it to be able to make websites, servers and games, why i cant just take over all functions, to spooky?
and yes, before i get any bad commentary, i AM familiar with java, so i got some experience.
ive been doing too much pre-programmed stuff so i wanted to know whats behind it all.

Comment: The only legitimate question here is "whats behind it all", but with such a broad scope it can be only answered with "lots and lots of other code".

Comment: A language which does everything well is definitely the ideal, but this is harder in practice. But there are attempts. See julia as a recent example.

Comment: If you can Java, it should be not very hard to learn C#. C# for instance can do almost every thing. C# MVC ASP.net for web and mobile website, webapp and C# for games, software just name it. Visual Studio Community is the IDE from Microsoft and is FREE. you can start, there is a lot of online learning. http://www.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Why as humans dont we conform to one written/spoken language why dont we make all languages conform to every country/person?

Comment: what does "programming language" relate to "assembly language" in the tag?

Answer (score 1):

What decides is the designers of those languages.  Why do we have so many kinds of pants, What is wrong with everyone wearing say Levi's 501's?  Why do we need so many fabrics and styles and numbers of pockets, when we only have two legs and jeans do pretty much everything we need.  Why so many kinds of different cars or trucks or houses or why is there more than one kind of smart phone?  Same reason why there are so many different programming languages.  Note there are many assembly languages for the same reason there are so many kinds of jeans or pants or cars or phones.  There are many different processors so first of you cannot have a single programming language that fully encompasses all the assembly languages.  Next many folks dont want to get in that deep so they want separation from the details and how they want to program and at what level varies.  Some dont want to know the details of the operating system much less processor (Java, python, etc).

The bottom line there already is (at least) one ultimate language for each architecture...assembly langauge, it does it all...but for some (sane) reason not everyone wants to program in that universal language.  Nor will they conform to one type of computer, operating system, smart phone or tablet.

Comment: Thanks! thats a very clear answer, so basicly it would actually be a better system to put EVERY assembly feature into 1 solid programming language, but us humans are just too stupid?